# Can I set two different domains to the same site in django "sites" framework?

Tags: django

Is there a way to set two domains to the same site instance without creating a new one, when using django's "sites" framework?

That means, having www.domain1.com and www.domain2.com to be considered as the same site in the framework.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this app : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-multisite . This is built over the Django's Site Framework, it creates an Alias's table which helps to manage multiple domains pointing to the same site. Again, this also provides various features which are handy for MultiSite Customizations.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: django-multisite looks nice, but I'm looking for something that can be controlled from the admin just like "sites" framework

Comment: Yup, the aliases can be controlled through the admin interface as well.